# Facebook Like Gate like_status is empty

Tags: php

so basically im trying to get a like gate working but the $like_status variable never changes so my condition to change to the liked content will never work. Does anyone know why this never changes? Have added my app to a page tab on facebook and it gets all the other variables $page_id, $page_admin, $country and $locale but not $like_status.

Thanks Charlie

See Code Below

```
<?php

    enter code here

require_once('AppInfo.php');

// Enforce https on production
if (substr(AppInfo::getUrl(), 0, 8) != 'https://' && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != '127.0.0.1') {
  header('Location: https://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  exit();
}

// This provides access to helper functions defined in 'utils.php'
require_once('utils.php');


require 'includes/facebook.php';


// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => AppInfo::appID(),
  'secret' => AppInfo::appSecret(),
  'cookie' => true
));

$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();

$page_id = $signed_request["page"]["id"];
$page_admin = $signed_request["page"]["admin"];
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
$country = $signed_request["user"]["country"];
$locale = $signed_request["user"]["locale"];

echo "<br>page id = $page_id";
echo "<br>page admin = $page_admin";
echo "<br>like status = $like_status";
echo "<br>country = $country";
echo "<br>locale = $locale";

function grokSignedRequest() 
{
    if (isset($_REQUEST['signed_request'])) 
    {
      $encoded_sig = null;
      $payload = null;
      list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $_REQUEST['signed_request'], 2);
      $sig = base64_decode(strtr($encoded_sig, '-_', '+/'));
      $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/'), true));
      return $data;
    }
    return false;
}



// call the function to parse the signed request
$sr_data = grokSignedRequest();



// check like status
if ($sr_data->page->liked==1) 
{
    include ('includes/index2.php');
} 

else
{
  include ('includes/index1.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Do you get any other signed_request variables? print_r($signed_request) and see what that gives you. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: @Robbie

This is what gets outputted:

`page id = 
page admin = 
like status = 
country = gb
locale = en_GB`
So only country and locale are being retrieved basically

Comment: Added my app to a page tab and I receive all the variables apart from like_status

Comment: Which is still empty for some reason

Comment: That was going to be my next question, you must have this on the tab to work. You have now liked the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your PHP code on a tab page, `like_status` is probably actually present, but set to a value of 0 (zero). Thus, the `echo` statement *seems* to be outputting nothing for `$like_status`, but in reality, it has a value of zero. To prove this try code like this:

```
if ($like_status == 0)
    echo "it's zero";
else 
    echo "it's not zero";
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, I didn´t see that @robbie solved this in the comments of the question

The user must arrive to the App from the page tab, and:

As with a Canvas Page, you will not receive all the user information accessible to your app in the signed_request until the user authorizes your app.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/#integrating